# When is 23:59:60 a valid time when programming?

Tags: time

I was reading the article about [Falsehoods programmers believe](https://spaceninja.com/2015/12/07/falsehoods-programmers-believe/) again, and came across this line:

> The time 23:59:60 is always invalid

And found this rather curious... why would this be a falsehood? In what scenario would 23:59:60 be a valid time to use as a programmer?
I'm probably missing something obvious, but I'd say this should always be 00:00:00?

Comment: If you had clicked the link on the page you referenced you'd see the author's explanation is _"When leap seconds are inserted, a minute will be 61 seconds long."_

Comment: Oh boy... I didn't even notice the titles were links... I feel stupid now...

Answer (score 2):

It is called Leap second. See wiki post:
[Leap second wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second)